# ImageMagick "Library not loaded: / Reason: image not found"

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I tried to install ImageMagick via Homebrew but when I run

```
magick logo: logo.gif
```

to try if the installation was successfull (as recommended) the terminal returns just:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Staff/ImageMagick-7.0.10/bin/magick
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I reinstalled ImageMagick, resets all environment variables and relocated its source into different directories but nothing works. Is there anything I missed or do I have to use a different path while using ImageMagick commands? For example:

```
magick identifly: /Users/Staff/Desktop/test.gif
```

Comment: Removed ghostscript tag as I can't see any relevance. It looks to me like your IM has been built to use X and you don't have X windows installed. Since you are using Homebrew I'll assume you are using a Mac (though it would be good to mention this). You'll need to install XQuartz to get an X server though I don't know if that is sufficient to get the dynamic libraries.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the answer. 
I have found another solution for the problem I wanted to install ImageMagick but maybe it will be useful another time.